# Stop Access 2007 From Using Scientific Notation When Importing Data

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

So I am importing a giant list of part numbers from an Excel file (converted from a CSV report from somewhere else) with VBA. The excel workbook is called on to prepare the data before importing including the following code that formats the part numbers to make sure the part numbers don't lose any info (just recently caught this):

`Columns("B:B").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True`

Once the excel sheets are made, I import them into tables using:

`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 5, "PartNumberX", "D:\Target\Import Data.xlsx", -1, "PartNumberX!" & PartDim`

Somewhere between the excel file and the Access table, the part numbers that do not have letters in them and are longer than 10 digits are being converted to scientific notation and losing the last few digits on the number. I can confirm that the excel file does not have scientific notation in it so I'm fairly certain it's happening somewhere in the importing process.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

-Edit:

When using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` it is creating the table "PartNumberX" - it does not already exist.

-Update:

So I thought that importing into a new table might be causing this issue. After importing into a pre-defined table with the part number field as a text field makes no difference in regards to preventing access form using scientific notation.

Comment: Is it possible to supply a dataset this will happen with, please?  I've seen it happen myself but am having a difficult time reproducing it.  If you can just provide a couple rows of data which can be pasted into an Excel book, that would be very useful.

Comment: These will be scientific notation:
957010802508 
957010802008
957010801608
-These Will be okay:
9405008080
9405008040
9405006080
91640SM4 0030     
91626SYA 0030     
91618S3N 0030

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, works fine for me.  Maybe the order of the data is important.  I even tried that several ways, but seems ok.

Comment: @ VBlades - When you were testing that, were you using the transfer spreadsheet into an already existing table or were you having it create the table? I forgot to mention this originally, but it is creating a table called "PartNumberX" that doe not already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had a dumb... I thought that since I formatted the original list of part numbers in Excel to be right the data a copied from it would also be formatted correctly. Obviously this was incorrect. I used

```
Columns("B:B").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

to format the other iterations of the part number list and it works fine now.

It's always the little things that get you -_-'